# How can I manually trigger the Activate event of a worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox "Ran"
End Sub
```

I have a button on my toolbar that I made. What I want it to do is trigger this method on the currently selected WorkSheet.

I figured I could do `Call ActiveWorksheet.Activate` or `Call Worksheet.Activate` but while these seem to execute without errors, the method is not called.

As a workaround I considered adding a public `DoActivate` method, but it seems a bit lame and I would likely have to fiddle with `CallByName` to get it to work (and developers would have to remember to implement this method on every worksheet).

Is there a reason why my Activate method is not calling manually via the above code, or a suitable workaround to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: For Activate event to get called, the sheet should become inactive followed by you switching to it and thereby make it active. How about moving the code from `Activate` and make it part of a public method in a bas module that accepts worksheet as parameter and you could do `OnActivate(Sheet1)` ?

Comment: Where is the button code located? What do you mean by *trigger this method on the currently selected WorkSheet*? Your example code doesn't relate to it. Do you know that the method need not be private? If you get rid of `Private`, you can call `ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Activate` from anywhere within the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code to a new Sub called OnActivate

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    OnActivate
End Sub

Private Sub OnActivate() 'or Public if you call from another module
    MsgBox "Ran"
End Sub
```

The `Worksheet_Activate()` event handler can be called manually from inside the module by `Worksheet_Activate` like any other sub (although this is IMO not a nice way to do it)

If you want to ensure all worksheets have the same method, then you can make them Implement an interface: e.g.

Class module: `IActivateHandler`

```
Public Sub OnActivate()
End Sub
```

Then in Sheet1, 2, 3 etc:

```
Implements IActivateHandler

Private Sub IActivateHandler_OnActivate()
    MeOnActivate
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MeOnActivate
End Sub

Private Sub MeOnActivate() 
    MsgBox "Ran"
End Sub
```

And the button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sheetToCall As IActivateHandler
    ' Debug.Assert TypeOf ActiveSheet Is IActivateHandler
    Set sheetToCall = ActiveSheet 'gets the IActivateHandler of the sheet, ensuring it is defined. Will error if it isn't
    sheetToCall.OnActivate 'runs the IActivateHandler_OnActivate() method of sheet1
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is though that you have to reference the Worksheet by name then in order to call `OnActivate`, whereas I want to use `ActiveWorksheet` or similar. I think I can use `CallByName` but I would have thought there'd be a way to trigger the Activate event so I don't have to do that

Comment: @NibblyPig Actually ActiveWorksheet should work too if the method is public. You may need to save it in a variable declared as object - this is the late bound method not very safe. Implementing an interface is the early bound type safe approach, but a bit more code

Answer (score 1):

You can call the activating event of any active sheet (without knowing its name) in this way:

Create the next event in `ThisWorkbook` code module. Or, simple copy the following code. Take care that such an event does not already exist:

```
Public Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox Sh.Name & " activated..."
    'the necessary code here...
End Sub
```

Then, call it from a standard module in the next way:

```
ThisWorkbook.Workbook_SheetActivate ActiveSheet
```

If you want excepting some sheets, you can adapt the event code to do it:

```
If sh.Name <> "MySheetName" then
    MsgBox Sh.Name & " activated..."
    'the necessary code here...
End if
```

If many sheets should be excepted, an array of sheet names should be built and use `Application.Match` to differentiate between the sheets to use their event and the other ones.

**Edited**:

If you need a piece of code written in an add-in (or any macro enabled workbook), able to catch the `Activate` event of a sheet **in any (other) open workbook**, you should proceed in the next way:

1. Copy the next declaration on top of the add-in `ThisWorkbook` code module (in the declarations area):

```
Public WithEvents appEvHandler As Application
```

2. In the same code module, copy the next code:

```
Private Sub appEvHandler_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
     If sh.Parent.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        MsgBox sh.Parent.Name & " workbook, sheet " & sh.Name & " activated..."
    Else
       Debug.Print "changed in this workbook..."
   End If
End Sub
```

3. Copy also the next `Sub`, which will activate the event:

```
Sub activateAppEvHandler() 
    Set appEvHandler = Application 'It can be placed in `Workbook_Open` event to be run when workbook opens
End Sub
```

4. If you want to inactivate it (for some reason...), use the next `Sub`:

```
Sub InactivateAppEvHandler() 
    Set appEvHandler = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. I must confess I am not sure I correctly understood what you need. I was asking for a scenario to be followed, but I tried imagining that this is what you want...

Comment: Presumably `ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Activate` won't work because it doesn't know if `ActiveSheet` has that method?

Comment: @NibblyPig So, you don't know if such an event exists in a sheet and want running it? And want doing that for all existing sheets? If so, you should use `Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` (in `WhisWorkbook` code module), which will be triggered by activation or called as I recommended above. I will adapt the above answer for this specific case.

Comment: @NibblyPig try `Dim sheet As Object: Set sheet =ActiveSheet: sheet.Worksheet_Activate` - this gets the default interface of whatever sheet ActiveSheet happens to refer to, so the method will be present. It is equivalent to `CallByName(sheet, "Worksheet_Activate", ...)`. Alternatively create a proper interface and have your worksheets implement it per my (updated) answer.

Comment: @Greedo Why declaring a useless variable, since `ActiveSheet` is an object accepted by the function? Exactly in the way I suggested above... Of course, instead of the message you can place any code you need.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right, in your examples sheet is already passed as a parameter declared As Object. I was just trying to explain why As Object helps in general. Oh and I was also looking at a previous version of your post where you didn't have the parameter

Comment: `Worksheet_Activate` is a built in function of vba that is called automatically upon an `Activate` event triggering. I am not sure if that was clear from my post and might be causing the confusion. I am trying to trigger an Activate event to make it run but it seems you can't do that in VBA.

Comment: @NibblyPig Activate event of **what**? If of a sheet, what problem does the above solution make? Please, try describing a scenario you have in mind and I will try making it working. Now, do you want a solution created in order **to trigger a sheet activate** event **in another workbook**?

Comment: When a sheet is activated, it automatically runs a `Worksheet_Activate` handler. What I wanted to do, was trigger that handler. However it seems that you cannot manually trigger events like you can in say, javascript.

Comment: @NibblyPig **Why do you need the event HANDLE**? If you catch **any ** sheet activate event and do what you want (in code) after that, is it not enough? Is it something I am missing? What do you want accomplishing, in fact?